# How to change loop condition in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, loops, matrix, conditional-statements

I run this code:

```
for i=1:length(matr)
```

...where `matr` is square matrix. In this loop the size of the `matr` changes, but it seems that the loop continues to run, until `i` doesn't not exceed the initial value of `length(matr)`

How to maintain the fresh of `length(matr)` in the loop's condition?

Here is my code.

```
for i=1:length(matr1)
       for j=1:length(matr1) 
           if((i~=j)&&(ismember(i,ind3)==0)&&(ismember(j,ind3)==0))
               if (i>length(matr1))||(j>length(matr1))
                   continue
               end
               ind1 = find_tree(matr1,i);
               ind2 = find_tree(matr1,j);
               b = is_isomorphic(matr1(ind1,ind1),matr1(ind2,ind2),encode(ind1),encode(ind2));
               if b,
                   number = number + length(ind1);
                   matr1(ind2,:) = [];
                   matr1(:,ind2) = [];
                   ind3 = find(summ_rows==-1);
               end
           end
       end
    end
```

I was managed to add

```
`if (i>length(matr1))||(j>length(matr1))`,
```

...because `i` and `j` exceeded the dimensions of the matrix.

Comment: Can you describe what your loop is trying to do? You probably should be using a `while` loop for this and not a `for` loop

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be using a `while` loop:

```
ii = 0;
while(ii <= length(matr))
    ii = ii + 1;

    %// Your loop code here: e.g. the following line that alters the size of matr
    matr = rand(randi(20) + 10);

end
```

Comment: Thank you. And, is it true, that bounds for a for-loop is calculated only before the initial iteration?

Comment: @restrest yes that is true as far as I know. Easy for you to test though

Comment: I think this might be related to the JIT acceleration. Could be you get different results once you [disable it](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/87225).

Comment: @bdecaf I haven't tested it but I wouldn't think so. `1:length(matr1)` creates a vector `[1,2,3...` first and then `i` will iterate over that. I'm pretty confident that this is set when you create the loop and does not change, JIT or no.